# How to query dbpedian and local ontology at the same time?

Tags: rdf, sparql, jena, owl, dbpedia

i'm trying to query remote dbpedia triple-store and my local rdf triple-store within a single Sparql query.Is it possible ? if it's so how? I already configured  Vitruoso server locally.

Answer (score 1):

Research SPARQL's `SERVICE` feature.